# How to setup OneToMany relationship?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I got a little issue.
I got 2 entities : User and Picture

A picture has a Foreign key users_id.
And every time I try to remove a User who has pictures I got a javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted because of this foreign key.
How do I configure my entities ?

Entity User

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "USER1")
    public class User1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "LOGIN", unique=true)
    private String login;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\." +
            "[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*" +
            "(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$", message="le mail n'est pas valide")

    @Column(name = "MAIL")
    private String mail;

    @Column(name = "ADMIN")
    private Boolean admin;

    @CascadeOnDelete
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Pictures> pictures;
```

Entity Pictures :

```
public class Pictures implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PATH")
    private String path;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NB_VIEW")
    private int nbView;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Column(name="METADATA")
    private String metadata;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User1 user;
```

EDIT :

I'm using a DAO to delete :

```
public void remove(T t) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().contains(t)?t:getEntityManager().merge(t));
}
```

When I delete a picture or a user who doesn't have pictures, it works pretty well. But everytime I try to delete on cascade a user with his pictures it works one in a million.

EDIT 2 : 
And here is the User's controller

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private UserDAO userDAO;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);
    private Map<Integer, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<>();

    public List<User1> getAllUsers() {
        return userDAO.findAll();
    }

    public User1 getUserByID(Integer id) {
        return userDAO.find(id);
    }

    public void submit() {
        List<User1> checkedUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (User1 user: getAllUsers()) {
            if (checked.get(user.getId())) {
                checkedUsers.add(user);
            }
        }

        checked.clear();

        if (checkedUsers.isEmpty()) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Veuillez sélectionner au moins un utilisateur à supprimer !", null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form-tabs-1:deleteButton", message);
        }

        for(User1 userToRemove: checkedUsers) {
            removeUser(userToRemove);
        }
    }

    public void removeUser(User1 userToRemove) {
        logger.info("removed user: " + userToRemove.getLogin());
        userDAO.remove(userToRemove);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Boolean> getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(Map<Integer, Boolean> checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you remove a user, what do you want to happen to the pictures that are referencing it?  If you want them removed as well, you can try the cascade.Remove option.  If you want them to continue to exist, you need to null out their reference to the user and merge those instances before it can be deleted.  Otherwise, you will have Pictures referencing deleted users - which results in the error you experience.

Comment: I notice the @CascadeOnDelete annotation, which I assume you are using to try and have the Pictures deleted.  As per http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_cascadeondelete.htm, this is an annotation that indicates the database is responsible for deleting the Pictures, so chances are you have not configured your database to delete these rows for you.  Try using EclipseLink's DDL generation to regenerate your tables or the ON DELETE CASCADE to your table manually.  The other alternative is to add the JPA cascade.remove options as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, firstly you need to clean-up you annotations.
And you need to decide what to do with you Pictures after User deletion :)

Both `orphanRemoval=true` and `CascadeType.REMOVE` are redundant, but they have different effects on relationship changes. For more details read:
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete

Try something like this:

```
   //@CascadeOnDelete
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",
     fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
     orphanRemoval=true,
     cascade={
     // CascadeType.REMOVE,
        CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Pictures> pictures;
```

Further, could you show code block, in which you'r removing User entity?
Also, try to remove `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` annotation.

Comment: It seems to work, I'll try some few tests to check if it's alright

Comment: yes, it was working but not now I don't understand why.

Comment: @Fr0z3n7, it looks like interference of annotations gives you unexpected EclipseLink behavior. Also, do you remove pictures from User's list before you remove them?

Comment: @Fr0z3n7, as i can guess, every time you want to delete User, you create new User's entity by it's primary key and pass it to your `public void remove(T t)`?

Comment: @ard4ers no I retrieve the user with a session's variable and use my controller to call the remove's method from the DAO.

Comment: My guess is maybe there is a problem with derby, but I'm not sure

Comment: for sure if you want more, feel free to tell

Answer (score 0):

I bilieve that your problem is @CascadeOnDelete. Removes this annotation and test again.

Comment: In my enviroment, with Hibernate 4.2 /JPA 2.0 your mapping removes the "Picture" by cascading normally. Perhaps would be a eclipse-link bug, try test with hibernate only for take a this doubt;